# Setting up common classes for access from other projects

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to set up two Java projects to have access to classes in another Java project.
So far, the situation is visible in the following image:

[image: projects]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/3T/uZ/2SyWc4rf/sharedproject.jpg))</sub>

However, I can't seem to import any classes from the Common project.

[image: common lowercase]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/3B/uJ/9pDSeke/common2.jpg))</sub>

[image: common uppercase]

I could just have multiple packages in a single project, but as far as I know only 1 jar can be compiled per project.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use Maven to get rid of this depndency system

Comment: SjB, I wish I could, however I did not choose to do it this way myself. This is a school homework project and there are strict specifications for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your "Common" project to libraries of project where you need to use classes from "Common" project.

For example right-click on "Clinet" project then "Properties"
In right menu choose "Libraries" and press button "Add Project..." and double-click on project "Common".

After that you can add `import common.Item;`

Also try to clean and build all your projects.

Comment: I did exactly that, yet it says the common package does not exist.

Comment: @DavidS. It's strange, because I did it in my NetBeans installation and it's work fine for me. Could you try to delete all libraries from your "Client" project(except jdk1.7) and try to add "Common" project again.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Netbeans on OS X Mavericks. A colleague also tried the same on Windows and it worked.

Comment: Today I opened NetBeans and the imports worked but only for XMLDocument and XMLMachine classes, not Item and Partner.

Comment: @DavidS. Ok, can you see what you have in `Clinet/nbproject/project.xml`? Have you there tag `<reference>` and in this tag note about your "Common" project?
And maybe `Item` and `Partner` classes have some errors, thats why they are not compiled and not present in `Common.jar`. Because if you can import `XMLDocument` and `XMLMachine` classes you absolutely  can import `Item` and `Partner` classes:)